# find most recent snapshot using xen command line

Tags: xen, snapshot

I am using Xen, and for each of our VM's we have set up a process to create a new snapshot of the VM every morning, with the last seven being kept.

I am now trying to write a script to test restoring the latest snapshot for each VM.

In Xen command line I can get a list of all the snapshots for a given VM using:

`xe snapshot-list snapshot-of=${vm_uuid}`

which returns seven entires in the following format:

```
uuid ( RO)                : fc6cb150-b264-830e-4fb9-7fec030e434d
          name-label ( RW): 20220616-0118
    name-description ( RW):
    is-vmss-snapshot ( RO): true
```

Is there an easy way to find out which is the latest one, as so far all I have to go is the date in the name-label (e.g. `20220616`), but the second part of the name (`0118`) changes with each snapshot, and as far as I can tell I can't use wildcards with the `name-label` option of `xe` e.g.

`xe snapshot-list snapshot-of=${vm_uuid} name-label=20220616*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out.

`today=$(date +%Y%m%d)`

`ss_name=$(xe snapshot-list snapshot-of=${vm_uuid} | grep ${today} | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{$1=$1};1')`

`ss_uuid=$(xe snapshot-list name-label="${ss_name}" | awk '{print $5}') echo $ss_uuid`

`echo ${ss_uuid}`

So while it isn't strictly finding the most recent one, so long as the snapshots contain the current date in the name, and a snapshot was taken today (and there is only one snapshot today), it should work.